# How to dismiss ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am trying to dismiss a ViewController in swift by calling `dismissViewController` in an `IBAction`

```
  @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    println("cancel")
}

@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    println("done")
}
```

[image: random image of a segue]

I could see the println message in console output but ViewController never gets dismissed. What could be the problem?

Comment: How did you present the view controller?

Comment: I did the mapping by setting a segue - "show", see the attached screenshot.

Comment: Try to use modal. If you use push, you should dismiss it with the pop method of the navigation controller.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

From you image it seems like you presented the ViewController using push

The `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is used to close ViewControllers that presented using modal

**Swift 2**

```
navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

**Swift 4**

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How would you do it for a 'Show Detail' segue?

Comment: For **Swift 2.2**  navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: For **Swift 3** navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

Answer (score 197):

I have a solution for your problem. Please try this code to dismiss the view controller if you present the view using modal:

Swift 3:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

OR

If you present the view using "push" segue

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same result, it does not dismiss the ViewController

Comment: How is this different to the method the OP used?

Comment: Conversation is useless if you don't react to my questions.

Comment: _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: For me 'dismiss' is taking me back to the login screen, pre where the tab controller is defined

Answer (score 22):

if you do this i guess you might not get println message in console,

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
  if(self.presentingViewController){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    println("cancel")
   }
}

@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
  if(self.presentingViewController){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    println("done")
  }    
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840235/cant-dismiss-my-previous-alertcontroller-completely. Any Help,please?I am stuck at that for so long who still cant find solution

Answer (score 20):

In Swift 3.0 to 4.0 it's as easy as typing this into your function:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or if you're in a navigation controller you can "pop" it:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: dismiss not working, because I'm using pushViewController. Only self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) working.

Answer (score 15):

1. embed the View you want to dismiss in a NavigationController
2. add a BarButton with "Done" as Identifier
3. invoke the Assistant Editor with the Done button selected
4. create an IBAction for this button
5. add this line into the brackets:

   ```
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   ```

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

instead of:

```
self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: add a ! to the navigationController and it works for me

Comment: @naturalc: Be aware that if navigationController is nil and you put !, the app will crash

Answer (score 12):

From Apple [documentations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss):

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented

Thus, it is a bad practise to just invoke the [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) method from it self.

What you should do if you're presenting it modal is:

```
presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you presenting a controller without a Navigation Controller, you can call the following code from a method of the presented controller.

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If your ViewController is presented modally, optional presentingViewController will be not nil and the code will be executed.

Answer (score 7):

Based on my experience, I add a method to dismiss me as extension to UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func dismissMe(animated: Bool, completion: (()->())?) {
        var count = 0
        if let c = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count {
            count = c
        }
        if count > 1 {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated)
            if let handler = completion {
                handler()
            }
        } else {
            dismiss(animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call this method to dismiss view controller in any `UIViewController` subclass. For example, in cancel action:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
   ...
   @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
     dismissMe(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So if you wanna dismiss your Viewcontroller use this. This code is written in button action to dismiss VC

```
  @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Since you used push presented viewController, therefore, you can use

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

***Don't create any segue from Cancel or Done to other VC*** and only write this code your buttons @IBAction

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you using the present method in the parent VC then you should call this function, to dismiss the child VC use this

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if you calling child VC by using push method, to dismiss the child VC use this

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the one way to dismiss present view controller and move back to previous view controller. You can do this through Storyboard only.

1. Open Storyboard
2. Right click on Cancel button and drag it to previous view controller, where you want to move back to previous controller
3. Now release the right click and you can see some actions which performs on cancel button
4. Now choose "popover present" option from list
5. Now you can dismiss your current view by click on cancel button

Please try this, It's working with me.

Second Way - Use - `navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Best luck..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840235/cant-dismiss-my-previous-alertcontroller-completely. Any Help,please?I am stuck at that for so long who still cant find solution

Comment: This is wrong. You are never dismissing the view you are instead presenting a new view controller on top of the current one, causing a memory leak. 
This will most likely get your app rejected from the app store.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, be aware that you might be dismissing the wrong view controller. For example, if you have an alert box or modal showing on top of another modal. (You could have a Twitter post alert showing on top of your current modal alert, for example). In this case, you need to call dismiss twice, or use an unwind segue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func close() {
  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The method called "dismissViewController" it only takes a single parameter, which I suppose would look like to dismiss animated to previous view, this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are presenting a ViewController modally, and want to go back to the root ViewController, take care to dismiss this modally presented ViewController before you go back to the root ViewController otherwise this ViewController will not be removed from Memory and cause Memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 3.0**

If you want to dismiss a presented view controller

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

If you use pushViewController to present new view controller, use this

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

Comment: Another copy paste answer

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```