# dismiss nsviewcontroller swift doesn't work

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsviewcontroller

That's the button action:

```
    @IBAction func readyPressed(sender: NSButton) {

    self.dismissController(Hardness)
    println(1)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("manual", sender: self)
    }
```

When I press the button, println works, segue works, but NSViewController "Hardness" doesn't close

Comment: Try self.dismissViewController(self)

Answer (score -11, accepted):

Please try using

> self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});

or use

> navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

as presented here

[how to dismiss a view controller in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668818/how-to-dismiss-view-controller-in-swift)

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, since the question is for MacOS not iOS. Please read more carefully it doesn't say UIViewController but NSViewController.

Answer (score 26):

Try this line to close the window: `self.view.window?.close()`

Comment: This seems to be what you use even if you open the `NSViewController` with a storyboard segue such as `Show`.

Answer (score 2):

You must add Action from button to First Responder - dismissController:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

you can try

NSViewController().dismiss(vc).

the viewcontroller to be dismissed should be passed as argument and the caller could be any NSViewController object.