# How to dismiss 2 view controller in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

How to dismiss 2 view controllers in Swift iOS?

Below is my code.

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.presentingViewController
        .presentingViewController
        .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I hope this link you help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668818/how-to-dismiss-view-controller-in-swift

Comment: Your code is already working fine on iOS 8.1+ and Swift 2.2+. Where was the issue?

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3+ version.** You can dismiss two view controllers at a time in Swift 3 with this below code.

```
func dismissTwoViews() {
    self.presentingViewController?
        .presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 4+ version**. just we need pop particular view controller use this extension

```
extension UINavigationController {

func popToViewController(ofClass: AnyClass, animated: Bool = true) {
    if let vc = viewControllers.filter({$0.isKind(of: ofClass)}).last {
        popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
}

func popViewControllers(viewsToPop: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
    if viewControllers.count > viewsToPop {
        let vc = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - viewsToPop - 1]
        popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

}

**And use like  this in your view controller class**

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as 
    Array {
                  if controller.isKind(of: 
    yourPopControllerName.self) {

   self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
                                _ =  
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, 
 animated: false)
                                    break
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Hm, this code looks exactly the same as posted in the question. What is the difference then? In Swift2 it dismissed only one controller, while in Swift3 it closes both?

Comment: @Mixaz I just tested on Swift 2.2 + iOS 8.1 (Xcode 7.3) and the code from the question was already working. So the difference can be either from an even older Swift version (**very unlikely!**) or actually from an older iOS version (like 8.0 or 7.x).

Answer (score 15):

There's special **unwind segue** for that purpose, it is intended to roll back to certain view controller in stack.

Let's call the topmost controller (where you go from) as *source* and the controller in stack (which you want to roll back to top) as *destination*.

1. create `IBAction` in *destination* to be triggered on unwind segue:

   `@IBAction func myUnwindAction(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}`

it can be empty.

2. in *source* controller create an unwind segue by dragging from the controller icon to exit one, it will find the action you created at the step 1. Call the segue `unwind`.
3. now you can issue that segue from code with regular

   `performSegueWithIdentifier("unwind", sender: nil)`

I described how to issue unwind segue from code. For buttons unwind segues can be created in IB directly by dragging a button to exit icon.

Also check this discussion for more info: [How to perform Unwind segue programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically)

Comment: When I do this, I get a runtime error, "Receiver has no segue with identifier"

Comment: This tutorial here might help as well: https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f

Comment: brilliant i got the error no seg with identifier unwind but in the end I just rightdraged the button to the exit on the top and removed the perform code i had in the button before and worked perfect thank you

Comment: Great answer. But how to avoid blinking of screens that being dismissed during ``unwind`` action?

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the tutorial link from @Mattk90 is easy to follow if you are confused by any of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can only dismiss one view controller at a time. Try this

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            let secondPresentingVC = self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController;
            secondPresentingVC?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

Created an extension for UIViewController that can pop UIViewControllers in NavigationController stack depending in supplied **number of times**

```
extension UIViewController {

    func pop(numberOfTimes: Int) {
        guard let navigationController = navigationController else {
            return
        }
        let viewControllers = navigationController.viewControllers
        let index = numberOfTimes + 1
        if viewControllers.count >= index {
            navigationController.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - index], animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think pop(numberOfTimes) seems to be misleading in terms of readability. How about `pop(numberOfViewControllers: Int)`