# How to programatically unwind or pop multiple viewControllers on back UIBarButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have 6 viewControllers in following manner.
`VCA`,`VCB`,`VCC`,`VCD`,`VCE`,`VCF`.

`mainVC`-->`VCA`-->`VCB`-->`VCC`-->`VCD`...`VCE`

`mainVC`-->`VCA`-->`VCD`...`VCF`

(-->) are connected by segues while (...) `VCE` and `VCF` are programatically `pushed in navigationController`.

My question is how can I pop multiple viewControllers from `VCD`,`VCE` or `VCF` to `VCA` on `Back` UIBarButton on `navigationController`

[image]

According to this StackOverFlow questions [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990507/dismiss-more-than-one-view-controller-simultaneously) and [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed) :-

Tried this code but it didn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.back(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
}

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   let presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
   presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {}) //.dismiss(animated:true, completion:{})
   })
}
```

Comment: try to implement [unwind segue](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/how-to-pass-data-in-an-unwind-segue-swift-3-1c3fa095cde1).

Comment: @pacification but I am not using segue for `VCE` and `VCF`, unwind segue won't work there

Comment: Is `mainVC` the navigation controller, and `VCA` the **root** controller for `mainVC`? Or is `mainVC` the root and `VCA` was pushed?

Comment: @Error any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that `VCA` was pushed onto `mainVC`, then your navigation controller stack is `[mainVC, VCA, VCB, ..., VCF]` or `[mainVC, VCA, VCD, ..., VCF]`, so you want to pop back to the VC at item 1 of the stack:

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if let vc = navigationController?.viewControllers[1] {
            _ = navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }

}
```

If what you really want to do is pop back to the **root** VC of the navigation controller, you can simply:

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

}
```

**Edit:**

Additional info:

```
// if you want to pop to the First VC, regardless of VC type
func popToFirst() {

    if let vc = navigationController?.viewControllers[1] {
        _ = navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("NO VC found as element 1 in navigation controller's stack")
    }

}

// if you want to pop to the First VC, but
// *only* if it is an instance of VCAViewController
func popToFirstOnlyIfA() {

    if let vc = navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as? VCAViewController {
        _ = navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("viewControllers[1] is NOT an instance of VCAViewController")
    }

}

// if you want to pop to an instance of VCAViewController,
// whether it's the root, first, second, third, etc VC in the stack
func popToAAnywhereInTheStack() {

    guard let aVCs = navigationController?.viewControllers else {
        print("No Array of View Controllers from navigationController!")
        return
    }

    for vc in aVCs {
        if vc is VCAViewController {
            _ = navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            return
        }
    }

    print("No instance of VCAViewController found in the stack")

}

// if you simply want to pop to the navigation controller's Root VC
func popToRoot() {

    _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. But I have a doubt, do you think that `viewController[1]` can be any other VC? Or anywhere it can go wrong?

Comment: Certainly, if the VC at index 1 is NOT an instance of VCA, then you would not get to VCA. See my edits for additional info, and additional ways to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Delete all view controllers from `navigationController?.viewControllers` between your current view controller (it will be the last) and view controller, then do `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`