# Dismiss two UIViewController at once without animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a stack of UIViewControllers like `A -> B -> C`. I want to go back to controller A from C. I'm doing it with below code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
// Background Thread
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
    })}
}
```

It works but controller B seen on screen although I set animated to false. How can I dismiss two UIViewControllers without showing the middle one (B)?

P.S: I can't just directly dismiss from root controller and also I can't use `UINavigationController`

I searched the community but can't find anything about the animation.

[Dismiss more than one view controller simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990507/dismiss-more-than-one-view-controller-simultaneously)

Comment: This could be easily achieved by using `UINavigationController`-based navigation instead of presenting view controllers from another view controller. That way you could use `setViewControllers` method to push/pop several view controllers at once, but having only one animation

Comment: Sorry I can't use navigation controller.

Comment: Did you try using a unwind segue?

Comment: I think you can dismiss controller B when show Controller C. Can be solution for you?  And then when you dismiss controller C you will be back to A.

Comment: Yes. It can be a solution for me. @gkolunia

Comment: I don't use storyboard :)

Comment: i reproduced your issue and Vc b doesn't show

Comment: let `A` dismiss the `B`, it will also dismiss the `C` in case if it is presented by `B`.

Comment: How can I do that? @RatulSharker

Comment: @Sh_Khan How can you present new controllers?

Comment: You can use protocol to communicate back to `A` from `C`, or use the `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController` only if you are sure about that, you presented two level of hierarchy

Comment: @RatulSharker I'm already dismissing it with presentingViewController.presentingViewController

Comment: @EmreÖnder - do you *want* the dismissal of `C` to be animated or not?

Comment: I want to dismiss C with or without animation. Animation is not a problem. The problem is B is seen on screen when I dismiss C so I want direct dismiss from C -> A

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Created a sample storyboard like this

[image]

The yellow view controller is type of `ViewController` and the button action is as follows

```
@IBAction func Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This looks working but I think because my controllers has lots of contents, It takes time. Btw, red one is also seen on your example

Answer (score 0):

I've created example for dismissing B controller before showing C controller. You can try it.

```
    let bController = ViewController()
    let cController = ViewController()

    aController.present(bController, animated: true) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now()+2, execute: {

            let presentingVC = bController.presentingViewController

            bController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {

                presentingVC?.present(cController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })
        })

    }
```

But on my opinion solution with using navigation controller would be the best for the case.  For example you can put just B controller into navigation controller -> present the navController onto A controller -> then show C inside the navController -> then dismiss from C controller whole navController -> And you will see A controller again. Think about the solution too.

**Another solution**

I've checked another solution.
Here extension which should solve your problem.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func dissmissViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        self.view.window?.insertSubview(toViewController.view, at: 0)
        dissmissAllPresentedControllers(from: toViewController)
        if toViewController.presentedViewController != self {
            toViewController.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    private func dissmissAllPresentedControllers(from rootController: UIViewController) {
        if let controller = rootController.presentedViewController, controller != self {
            controller.view.isHidden = true
            dissmissAllPresentedControllers(from: controller)
        }
    }

}
```

Usage

```
let rootController = self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController! //Pointer to controller which should be shown after you dismiss current controller
self.dissmissViewController(toViewController: rootController, animated: true)
```

// All previous controllers will be dismissed too, 
   // but you will not see them because I hide them and add to window  of current view.

But the solution I think may not cover all your cases. And potentially there can be a problem if your controllers are not shown on whole screen, all something like that, because when I simulate that transition I don't consider the fact, so you need to fit the extension maybe to your particular case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't wanna loose B on every time I open C. Sometimes user wants to go back to B

Comment: @EmreÖnder In the case only solution with navigation controller perfectly fits to your requirements. Which I described in my answer above. If you need I can make example for the case too.

Comment: Thank you for that but I can't use nav controller in my project now because It has lots of controllers and codes. This A, B, C is just an example.

Comment: I've got it. I have another thought, But it needs to be check, when i check it i will be back to you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.

Comment: @EmreÖnder I've edited my answer with new solution for you.

Comment: I can check it tomorrow. Thank you so much.