# swift iOS is all view controller running in the background of my app

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

When I start my app and then check the debug inspector I (the once where I can drag around my app/views in 3d) I see that all old views is showing up in the background of the current VC/view.

Does that mean that my old views is running in the background?
Is there a way to reset the root VC so that the old views doesn't get stacked up?

Comment: look at viewWillDisappear and also check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668818/how-to-dismiss-view-controller-in-swift

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Thanks but that is for dismissing VC. I don't want to dismiss my VC I only wonder why I can see all my VC's stacked?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller?  If so then the view controllers will be on the stack so that you can go back to them.  You can manipulate the navigation controllers stack directly to reset the root view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. How can I anipulate the navigation controllers stack?
I am entering by modal segue and not push. But I still want the new VC to become the first one in the navigation controller stack

Comment: Have you read the UInavigationController documentation?  You can simply manipulate the `viewControllers` array but you may be better off rethinking your app design.  Why use a navigation controller if you aren't navigating through a stack of view controllers?