# Presenting a new view controller from selected table row modally

Tags: ios

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let memeShowViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ShowMeme") as! MemeShowViewController
        memeShowViewController.memeImage = appDelegate.memes[indexPath.row].memeImage
        self.navigationController!.presentViewController(memeShowViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So I have a tableview that has a nav controller embedded in it and when I present the `memeShowViewController` modally I was wondering why the view of the `memeShowViewController` has a black background color when I didn't change it to be black.

**In storyboard:**

[image]

**In simulator**

[image]

Right now I'm just adding a navigation bar to the segue-ed view controller, I was wondering if there is a better way to do as the only functionality I need from the navigation bar is for the done button to segue back to the `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

The background `window` has a black background so if your app doesn't cover any part of the `window` (or `alpha = 0`) you'll see that black background.

Comment: But doesn't the view cover the whole window?

Comment: It's supposed to, can you put a break point on `viewDidAppear` and check the frame?

Comment: Yeah I checked and it does, although I fixed it by wrapping my view controller in a navigation controller

Comment: So the issue is fixed now?

Comment: Well now I can't add a "done" button to segue back to my original view controller so I guess not really. I'm trying to use code to do it but I don't know how to segue back to the original view controller using code. I've created the button and it shows but I don't know how to write the function to go back

Comment: Here's how it's in the code: `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});` ([original link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24669141/2177402))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96463/discussion-between-yellowpillow-and-islam-q).