# Swift dismissViewController from Segue - macOS

Tags: swift, macos, segue

I have a secondary ViewController that appears programmatically via a Storyboard segue:

```
func actioncall ()
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showIgnoreVC", sender: self)

}
```

)

This function is part of the main ViewController, and is called via an NSNotification from the AppDelegate, which in turn is triggered by a Menu Item click.

However, even though the segue is connected to the main ViewController, the following code does not dismiss the secondary view:

```
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any)
{
    print("Hello?  Gonna close?")

    self.presenting?.dismissViewController(self)
}
```

There are no errors, the function is called upon the correct **Dismiss** button click, but the secondary view does not dismiss.  I have tried every variation of dismissViewController to no avail.

When I use a button on the Main view to activate the same segue, everything works as it is supposed to.  I simply do not wish to clutter up the main View with a bunch of buttons.

Any ideas are appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: When this line `self.presenting?.dismissViewController(self)` executes, what is the value of `self.presenting`?

Comment: @DaveWeston, good question.  Using `let x = self.presenting! as NSViewController`, the app crashes with **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**.  Apparently there is no viewController presenting.

Answer (score 0):

dismissViewController works only for view controllers, that were presented modally (using `Present Modally Segue`)
As said in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668818/how-to-dismiss-viewcontroller-in-swift), you should dismiss view controllers, presented by `Show Segue`, like this:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: dismissViewController works for view controllers presented as a sheet, and show as well.  In this project, there is no navigationController.  Thank you for your input anyway.