# UINavigationBar BarButtomItem not dismissing the view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have created UINavigationBar programatically and added barbuttonitem, the problem is when I click on that image, respective method is calling but view controller is not dismissing.

**LocateVehicle**

```
class LocateVehicle: UITableViewController{

let kCloseCellHeight: CGFloat = 130
let kOpenCellHeight: CGFloat = 488
let kRowsCount = 10
var cellHeights: [CGFloat] = []

let dataArr = ["Running", "Stopped", "Idle", "Running"]

@IBAction func backBarButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.contentInset.top = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    cellHeights = Array(repeating: kCloseCellHeight, count: kRowsCount)
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = kCloseCellHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "background"))
}

 }
// MARK: - TableView
extension LocateVehicle {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArr.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard case let cell as CustomLocateVehicleCell = cell else {
        return
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    if cellHeights[indexPath.row] == kCloseCellHeight {
        cell.unfold(false, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        cell.unfold(true, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    cell.number = dataArr[indexPath.row]
//        cell.statusLabel.text = dataArr[indexPath.row]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoldingCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLocateVehicleCell

    let durations: [TimeInterval] = [0.26, 0.2, 0.2]
    cell.durationsForExpandedState = durations
    cell.durationsForCollapsedState = durations

//        cell.liveTrackButton.tag = indexPath.row;


   return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath.row]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FoldingCell

    if cell.isAnimating() {
        return
    }

    var duration = 0.0
    let cellIsCollapsed = cellHeights[indexPath.row] == kCloseCellHeight
    if cellIsCollapsed {
        cellHeights[indexPath.row] = kOpenCellHeight
        cell.unfold(true, animated: true, completion: nil)
        duration = 0.5
    } else {
        cellHeights[indexPath.row] = kCloseCellHeight
        cell.unfold(false, animated: true, completion: nil)
        duration = 0.8
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }, completion: nil)

  }
}
```

**LiveTrack**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    setNavigationBar()
  }

 func setNavigationBar() {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: screenSize.width, height: 44))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar);
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "AP 16 BD 5678");
    let image = UIImage(named: "ic_chevron_left_white")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backAction));
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneItem;
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false);
 }

 @IBAction func backAction(_ sender: Any) {
    print("back working")
   //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
     dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

I am navigation to view controller from tableview cell

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LiveTrackStoryboard") as! LiveTrack
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    //show window
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = view
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you present the VC

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668818/how-to-dismiss-viewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: @ThreeCoins check my updated post

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tried all the solutions but no luck

Comment: are you used the `rootViewController` , then how can you use dismiss

Comment: Can you please give me the solution, i am new to ios, if i use resent(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() it is throwing error, i got the above solution to navigate

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: this is the error whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae this line appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = view makes your controller (where you navigated) a root controller in other words this is the entry point now , there is nothing to go back. Either perform a push instead of making it root and then where you have left bar button action perform pop.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma thanks for reply, I understand the problem, but except that line no other solutions worked for me to navigate to next view controller, i am using that from tableviewcell

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Can you explain this! Sorry I don't understand your problem. How to present it ?

Comment: I need to navigate to View controller by selecting the button which is presented in TableViewCell. No other solutions worked for me except the above. As per  
@Tushar Sharma i understand the problem, but i need solution to this

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I think you want to navigate a view controller when the cell's button is tapped. Right? It's my opinion.

Comment: @Mannopson yes..

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae where is the code to perform push in above updated code?

Comment: @ Tushar Sharma do i need to add any code related to navigation in LocateVehicle

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae exactly tableViewController is subclass of viewController , and you can only perform push from there, add button target in cellForRowAt method of table, and then in method body perform push.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma can you please edit my code to solve that

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I have updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159278/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-minnukaanae).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button target in `cellForRowAt`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoldingCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLocateVehicleCell

    let durations: [TimeInterval] = [0.26, 0.2, 0.2]
    cell.durationsForExpandedState = durations
    cell.durationsForCollapsedState = durations
    cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked()), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Perform `Push` on cell button action(You are making second controller root controller, so there is nothing to go back, so don't do that instead perform push, and add controller to stack) make sure your `root controller` is embedded to `navigationController`. -:

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton){
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LiveTrackStoryboard") as! LiveTrack
    // TO PUSH
        navigationController?.pushViewController(view,animated: true)
    // TO PRESENT
     present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now in second controller where you have `leftBarButton` pop to previous controller -:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setNavigationBar()
      }

     func setNavigationBar() {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: screenSize.width, height: 44))
        self.view.addSubview(navBar);
        let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "AP 16 BD 5678");
        let image = UIImage(named: "ic_chevron_left_white")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backAction));
        navItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneItem;
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false);
     }

     @IBAction func backAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print("back working")
   // TO POP
      self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   // TO DISMISS
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```

**Perform any based on your need.**

You also don't need to embed navigationController as root if you don't want to perform push.

Comment: I am not using Navigation Controller in my project

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae then you can present next controller and then dismiss it.

Comment: value of type Custom table cell has no member navigationController

Comment: My CustomTableCell class not allowing me to write present(...)

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae show your table class code, where are you performing push and present ? it needs to be done in controller class , and not in custom cell class.

Comment: It is giving error use of unresolved identifier buttonClicked and another error in buttonClicked method for  use of unresolved identifier navigation controller

Comment: ,i have one doubt, my tableview cell has multiple textviews, getting data from json while parsing the json object, in android I am storing in arraylist and using bean class to set and get data, so in IOS what is the process, is there any concept for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae post a new question for same, I would answer this there.

Comment: i have seen some tutorials, i have found model class to implement this scenario, i'll try that.